# Solr - Can't search when term ends with "y"

Tags: solr, solr-schema

This problem seems really ridiculous.
I always get 0 results when searching for entries that end with "y". I **know** they exist.

**0 Results:**

- Barthy
- Tony
- Maxy

**x Results:**

- Barth
- Ton
- Max

With any of the last three I get the desired results (`Barthy B`, `Tony Banderas`, `Maxy Doe`, ...)

Words that contain but don't end with "y" are totally fine (`Rayman`, ...)

What is happening? Could something like this be achieved with the schema (if yes, how? So that I can search for it)

Any other idea where to start looking?

Comment: could you please share the schema.xml?

Comment: can you check if your fieldType consists of solr.PorterStemFilterFactory...? porter is a transforming algorithm for English language that reduces any of the forms of a word such as walks, walked to walk...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti thank you for saving me a lot of time. It was a SnowBallPorter-thingy. Post an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `PorterStemFilterFactory` or `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` from the fieldType.

As porter is a transforming algorithm for English language that reduces any of the forms of a word such as `walks, walked to walk`.

Comment: Alternatively you can also try putting the filter in both the field's index and query configuration, so you can have stemming.

Answer (score 0):

In my config, it was SnowballPorterFilterFactory and not lowercase snowballporterfilterfactory